# Mongodb: project to get only numeric values from string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

Is there any logic as javascript replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') method. 
to get only numeric values of string.

Get only integer from string

Sample Document:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "planName" : "Options Silver 1431B"
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "planName" : "Options Silver 1431A"
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "planName" : "myOptions 1431A"
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "planName" : "myOptions 1431"
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "planName" : "myOptions 1431A",

}
```

Result:

```
   {
        "_id" : "1",
        plan_id: "1431"
   },
   {
        "_id" : "1",
        plan_id: "1431"
   },
   {
        "_id" : "1",
        plan_id: "1431"
   },
   {
        "_id" : "1",
        plan_id: "1431"
   },
   {
       "_id" : "1",
        plan_id: "1431"
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three steps using aggregation framework:

1. Convert your string to an array of characters using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) with [$substrCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/)
2. Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to keep only numeric values (`"0"` - `"9"`)
3. Use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) to concat them back into one string

   ```
   db.col.aggregate([
       {
           $addFields: {
               chars: {
                   "$map":{
                       "input":{
                           "$range":[
                               0,
                               {
                                   "$strLenCP":"$planName"
                               }
                           ]
                       },
                       "in":{
                           "$substrCP":[
                               "$planName",
                               "$$this",
                               1
                           ]
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       },
       {
           $project: {
               numbers: {
                   $filter: {
                    input: "$chars",
                    as: "char",
                    cond: { $and: [
                       { $gte: [ "$$char", "0" ] },
                       { $lte: [ "$$char", "9" ] }
                     ] }
                 }
               }
           }
       },
       {
           $project: {
               plan_id: { 
                   $reduce: {
                     input: "$numbers",
                     initialValue: "",
                     in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ])
   ```